# Java Nested Array to Recursion Method

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, recursive-datastructures

Here is my code, which is being used to find all the combination from an array
Is there any recursive way to increase the flexibilty of coding ?

Result of here :
1324
1342
1234
1243
1432
1423
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
4132
4123
4312
4321
4213
4231

```
class Main {

  // Find all combination from an array
  public static void findAllConbinationFromArray(int ary[]){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ary.length ; i++){
      for(int j = 0 ; j < ary.length ; j++){
        for(int k = 0 ; k < ary.length ; k++){
          for(int l = 0 ; l < ary.length ; l++){
            if(check(i, j, k, l)){
              System.out.print(ary[i] + "" + ary[j] + "" + ary[k] + "" + ary[l]);
              System.out.println(); 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Check and skip if it selects same value
  public static boolean check(int ... elemt){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < elemt.length ; i++){
      int current = elemt[i];
      for(int j = 0 ; j < elemt.length ; j ++){
        if(i != j){
          if(current == elemt[j])
            return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ary[] = {1, 3, 2, 4};
    findAllConbinationFromArray(ary);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go through all permutations of an array recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794268/go-through-all-permutations-of-an-array-recursively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive way to produce all permutations of an array.

```
public class Permute {

void swap(int[] arr, int x, int y) {
    int temp = arr[x];
    arr[x] = arr[y];
    arr[y] = temp;
}

void permute(int[] arr) {
    permute(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

//i - start index
//n - end index
void permute(int[] arr, int i, int n) {
    int j;
    if (i == n)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    else {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            swap(arr, i, j);
            permute(arr, i + 1, n);
            swap(arr, i, j); // swap back
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    new Permute().permute(arr);
}
```

}

Comment: You are welcome. If it is a right answer don't be hesitate to put correct answer flag ;)

Comment: And do you have any non-recursive way to solve this problem efficiently

Comment: @alantheweasel If you want a better way to solve it non recursively, you will have to post another question.

Comment: @alantheweasel this post will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799078/permutation-algorithm-without-recursion-java